# How can I stop Google Analytics from tracking a certain user?

Tags: google-analytics

I have the Google Analytics module installed. How can I prohibit the code snippet appearing on pages served to a particular user. Say user #15, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider creating a separate user role for that purpose and disabling Google Analytics for that role. The setting can be found at the module config page (/admin/config/system/googleanalytics) under Tracking Scope -> Roles.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to create a new role just to stop tracking a single user. If you want the user to be able to opt-out from being tracked, go to the Google Analytics module settings page (/admin/config/system/googleanalytics) and under Tracking Scope -> Users, select:

"Tracking on by default, users with opt-in or out of tracking permission can opt out"

[image: Google Analytics module settings page]

Then you can give user roles you wish (e.g. "Authenticated User") permission to opt-out of Google Analytics tracking ("Opt-in or out of tracking").

The user can then log in to their account and opt out of tracking.

Having said that, if you want to prohibit a certain user from being tracked, or you don't want to give anybody else permission to opt out, then I agree that adding a new user role might be the best way to go for this.